# Creating a 2 page PDF with a different background image on the second page

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to use itextsharp to take dynamic information and generate a PDF with it.. The PDF's use a background Image on each page which is different and the text content is positioned where it needs to be using the contentByte helper. Thats the plan anyways. I hit a hang up when I tried to add another page and then drop the image and text onto that page... My first page ends up with the image that should be on my second page and the first page image fails to display at all on either page... My code so far is as follows:

```
                Function ID_and_Parking(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim _reg_info As reg_info = db.reg_info.Single(Function(r) r.id = id)
        Dim _conf_info As conf_info = db.conf_info.Single(Function(f) f.id = 0)
        Dim _name As String = String.Empty


        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_reg_info.name_tag_pref) Then
            _name = _reg_info.name_tag_pref
        Else
            _name = _reg_info.first_name + " " + _reg_info.last_name
        End If
        Dim _LastName As String = _reg_info.last_name
        Dim _Employer As String = _reg_info.business_name
        Dim _Class_1 As String = _reg_info.tues_class
        Dim _Class_2 As String = _reg_info.wed_class
        Dim _Class_3 As String = _reg_info.thur_class
        Dim _Class_4 As String = _reg_info.fri_class
        Dim _BeginDate As String = _conf_info.conf_start_date
        Dim _endDate As String = _conf_info.conf_end_date
        Dim _dates As String = _BeginDate + "-" + _endDate

        If IsDBNull(_reg_info.tues_class) Then
            _Class_1 = ""
        End If
        If IsDBNull(_reg_info.wed_class) Then
            _Class_2 = ""
        End If
        If IsDBNull(_reg_info.thur_class) Then
            _Class_3 = ""
        End If
        If IsDBNull(_reg_info.fri_class) Then
            _Class_4 = ""
        End If


        Dim pdfpath As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\PDF_Files\"
        Dim imagepath As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\PDF_Files\"
        Dim _PdfName As String = _LastName + ".pdf"
        Dim doc As New Document
        doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER)
        doc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        Dim _PnameFont As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
        Dim BF_Times As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, False)
        Dim _Parking_Name As New Font(BF_Times, 18, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
        Dim _Parking_Date As New Font(BF_Times, 24, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)



        Try
            Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(pdfpath + _PdfName, FileMode.Create))
            doc.Open()


            Dim jpg As Image = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/Parking_Pass.jpg")
            jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING
            jpg.ScaleToFit(612, 792)
            doc.add(jpg)
            Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
            'Render Parking Permit
            cb.BeginText()
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 16)
            cb.SetTextMatrix(145, 135.5)
            cb.ShowText(_BeginDate)
            cb.EndText()

            cb.BeginText()
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 16)
            cb.SetTextMatrix(429, 135.5)
            cb.ShowText(_endDate)
            cb.EndText()



            Dim _idJpg As Image = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/Id_Tag.jpg")
            Dim imageWidth As Decimal = _idJpg.Width
            Dim imageHeight As Decimal = _idJpg.Height

            doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER)


            _idJpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING
            _idJpg.ScaleToFit(612, 792)
            doc.NewPage()
            doc.Add(_idJpg)

            cb.BeginText()
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 18)
            cb.SetTextMatrix(100, 50)
            cb.ShowText(_name)
            cb.EndText()

            cb.BeginText()
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 18)
            cb.SetTextMatrix(200, 100)
            cb.ShowText(_Employer)
            cb.EndText()

            cb.BeginText()
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 18)
            cb.SetTextMatrix(300, 150)
            cb.ShowText(_Class_1)
            cb.EndText()

            cb.BeginText()
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 18)
            cb.SetTextMatrix(310, 50)
            cb.ShowText(_Class_2)
            cb.EndText()

            cb.BeginText()
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 18)
            cb.SetTextMatrix(320, 50)
            cb.ShowText(_Class_3)
            cb.EndText()

            cb.BeginText()
            cb.SetFontAndSize(BF_Times, 18)
            cb.SetTextMatrix(330, 50)
            cb.ShowText(_Class_4)
            cb.EndText()



            doc.Close()
        Catch dex As DocumentException
            Response.Write(dex.Message)
        Catch ioex As IOException
            Response.Write(ioex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)



        End Try



        Return RedirectToAction("showUserPDF", New With {.pdfName = _PdfName})


    End Function
```

I have been all over every forum about this but all of the information I have found seems to be off from what I am looking for, OR maybe I am just going about this the wrong was all together... Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have figured out the issue I overlooked my placement of the newpage and the image placement... I had the 2nd page image before the newpage... Thanks for your help... If anyone else neededs to dynamically fill a image with data the above solution works...

Answer (score 1):

In your code you've got this:

```
    Dim jpg As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/Parking_Pass.jpg")
    jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING
    jpg.ScaleToFit(612, 792)
```

But you are never actually adding `jpg` to the `doc`

Comment: Good eye... That was in there before because I layed out the page placement for that part, but anyways... Now I have a problem.. It appears that both images are getting put on the same page... The First image and then the second one gets dumped on top of it.. I thought by putting it below the add page constructor it would show on the second page but they are both ending up on the same page.. Any Ideas????

Comment: I actually have figured out the issue I overlooked my placement of the newpage and the image placement... I had the 2nd page image before the newpage... Thanks for your help... If anyone else neededs to dynamically fill a image with data the above solution works...